# if all else fails tcl script fails

Tags: tcl, expect, scp

I am trying to make a script to transfer  file to another device. Since I cannot account for every error that may occur, I am trying to make an if-all-else fails situation:

```
spawn scp filename login@ip:filename
expect "word:"
send "password"

expect {
    "100" {
        puts "success"
    } "\*" {
        puts "Failed"
    }
}
```

This always returns a Failed message and does not even transfer the file, where as this piece of code:

```
spawn scp filename login@ip:filename
expect "word:"
send "password"

expect "100"
puts "success"
```

shows the transfer of the file and prints a success message.

I cant understand what is wrong with my if-expect statement n the first piece of code.

Comment: Can you tell me why you have used `\*` ? Are you intend to match literal dollar sign ?

Comment: I thought it would act like an if-else statement, where if it matched the 100, it would jump out. otherwise, if there was no 100, then it would be considered an error, therefore it would print a fail

Comment: @Dinesh `*` is called an asterisk. `$` is the dollar sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of `\*`. The backslash will be translated by Tcl, thereby making the `\*` into `*` alone which is then passed to `expect` as

```
expect *
```

As you know, `*` matches anything. This is like saying, *"I don't care what's in the input buffer. Throw it away."* This pattern always matches, even if nothing is there. **Remember that `*` matches anything, and the empty string is anything!** As a corollary of this behavior, this command always returns immediately. It never waits for new data to arrive. It does not have to since it matches everything.

I don't know why you have used *. Suppose, if your intention is to match literal  asterisk sign, then use `\\*`.

The string `\\*` is translated by Tcl to `\*`. The pattern matcher then interprets the `\*` as a request to match a literal `*`.

```
expect "*" ;# matches * and? and X and abc
expect "\*" ;# matches * and? and X and abc
expect "\\*" ;# matches * but not? or X or abc
```

Just remember two rules:

1. Tcl translates backslash sequences.
2. The pattern matcher treats backs lashed characters as literals.

**Note :** Apart from question, one observation. You are referring your expect block as a `if-else` block. ***It is not same as If-Else block.***

The reason is, in traditional `if-else` block, we know for sure that at least one of that block will be executed. But, in `expect`, it is not the case. It is more of like multiple `if` blocks alone.

Comment: The Idea I was going for was that, if the `100` matched, then it would jump out of the expect statement (similar to an if-else statement). How do I go about configuring it like an if else statement?

Comment: As i mentioned, it's not `if-else` block. By the way, What is your expectation for else block. ?

Comment: Thou can make use of `timeout` instead of `\*`, as a fail safe scenario. If 100 appears, it will print 'success'. If timeout happens, it will print 'failure'. You can change `timeout` value as `set timeout 60`. Default value is 10s.

Comment: My expectation: If a 100 is shown (this would represent 100%) therefore the file was successfully transferred. If anything else showed up, other than 100, this would mean the file transfer failed. Therefore it would print the fail message

Comment: `expect` is really a “wait until one of these matches or we timeout” block. Which doesn't really map to any standard structured programming notation (though it's relatively close to some of the things that concurrent logic systems can do).